# How to plot figures inside a table

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization

In some research papers, I often met some elaborate visualization which combining the advantages of figures and tables.

An example I clipped from [paper here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1674200113002228) is as follows:

[image]

The individual plots (scatter with error-bar) and the three-line table are all easy to prepare. However, I found it is difficult to generate an imitation using Python language.

Obviously, we can plot lines and text around the subplot to mimic the tables. But I was looking forward to some more advanced methods to achieve this task.

Any advices would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to head over to the [TeX stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) sister site. I'm pretty confident that this table was generated in LaTeX

Comment: One can observe that the points in the plot to not perfectly align to the table. Hence my guess is that the author used an image and positionned and scaled it to where it would roughly fit into the table. This can be done in latex.